# Solrcloud node is not comming up

Tags: solr

I have a Solrcloud cluster running with 2 nodes, configured with one shard and one replica. Now I have added a node on a new server, registered with the same three zookeepers. The node shows up inside the tree of the Solrcloud admin GUI under "live nodes". However it is not inside the graphical view and it shows 0 cores available while the other admin interface shows the available core.

Is there something I have to do in order to add a node, despite registering it? This is the startup command I am using:

```
bin/solr start -cloud -s server/solr2 -p 8983 -z zk1:2181,zk1:2182,zk1:2183 -noprompt
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered in the zookeeper logs that the embedded zookeeper will only run in "Standalone Mode" which means it will not create a cluster or ensemble. Your two node cluster is really just a 1 node (zookeeper) cluster with the second node's Solr using the first node's zookeeper to run off. It's a little misleading because the Solr web interface says two (Solr) nodes are active. Don't mistake this for two (Zookeeper) nodes being active.

The Solr docs specifically says "embedded zookeeper use in production is not supported" so they cripple it. I think it's a bit of a waste personally, if you can simplify the installation by embedded zookeeper, then yay! But alas no. I even tried to set the zoo.cfg to do cloud mode, but Solr seems to be bypassing this setting somehow.

It's best to just run your own zookeeper (really easy to set up... just don't try anything advanced until you follow the tutorial word for word to get a win).

I hope this helps. I was driven mad by it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal as running zookeeper as an embedded server on prod is not recommended, but from the admin UI it shows you which nodes have stopped or are dead. You can start like so:

```
/opt/solr/bin/solr stop -all
/opt/solr/bin/solr start -cloud -p 8983 -s /opt/solr/example/cloud/node1/solr
/opt/solr/bin/solr start -cloud -p 7574 -z localhost:9983 -s /opt/solr/example/cloud/node2/solr
/opt/solr/bin/solr start -cloud -p 7575 -z localhost:9983 -s /opt/solr/example/cloud/node2/solr
```

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/getting-started-with-solrcloud.html#restarting-nodes